# Match valueS in two files and replace in selected columns

Tags: awk

If values for columns 1,2 and 5 in file1 match with columns 1,2 and 9 in file2.

Then replace values in column 1,2 in file2, using the information of columns 3,4 of file1

Add character R for lines replaced and O for lines not replaced in the output file. Also add columns 1 and 2 from file1 for matched records.

**`file1`**

```
37267.00  37181.00  37267.00  37181.00  2605  
37269.00  37181.00  37267.00  37184.00  2605  
37271.00  37181.00  37271.00  37181.00  2603  
36829.00  37185.00  36820.00  37184.00  2605  
36831.00  37187.00  36831.00  37185.00  2605  
36833.00  37189.00  36833.00  37189.00  2605  
36835.00  37191.00  36831.00  37194.00  2606
```

**`file2`**

```
37267.00  37181.00  8424   36840.00  37260.00  37146.00  37612.00  36  2605
37269.00  37181.00  8424   36840.00  37260.00  37146.00  37612.00  36  2605
37271.00  37181.00  8424   36840.00  37260.00  37146.00  37612.00  36  2603
36829.00  37185.00  8640   36840.00  37260.00  37146.00  37624.00  36  2605
36831.00  37187.00  8640   36840.00  37260.00  37146.00  37624.00  36  2605
36833.00  37189.00  8640   36840.00  37260.00  37146.00  37624.00  36  2605
36835.00  37191.00  8640   36840.00  37260.00  37146.00  37624.00  36  2606
```

**`output desired`**

```
37267.00  37181.00  8424   36840.00  37260.00  37146.00  37612.00  36  2605  O 37267.00  37181.00
37267.00  37184.00  8424   36840.00  37260.00  37146.00  37612.00  36  2605  R 37269.00  37181.00
37271.00  37181.00  8424   36840.00  37260.00  37146.00  37612.00  36  2603  O 37271.00  37181.00
36820.00  37184.00  8640   36840.00  37260.00  37146.00  37624.00  36  2605  R 36829.00  37185.00
36831.00  37185.00  8640   36840.00  37260.00  37146.00  37624.00  36  2605  R 36831.00  37187.00
36833.00  37189.00  8640   36840.00  37260.00  37146.00  37624.00  36  2605  O 36833.00  37189.00
36831.00  37194.00  8640   36840.00  37260.00  37146.00  37624.00  36  2606  R 36835.00  37191.00
```

**I tried**

```
awk '
FNR==NR{
  a[$1 $2 $5]=$3 $4
  b[$3 $4]=$3
  c[$3 $4]=$4
  next
}
($1 in a){
  $1=b[$1]
  $2=c[$1]
  $1=a[$1]
  found=1
}
{
  $0=found==1?$0",R":$0",O"
  sub(/^...../,"&,")
  $1=$1
  found=""
}
1
' FS=" " file1 FS=" " OFS=" " file2
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: I believe your expected output is not clear, please fix it.

Comment: We've definitely discussed in the past that `a bc` = `abc` and `ab c` = `abc` so you shouldn't just concatenate fields like `b[$3 $4]` to try to create a unique array index, you should use SUBSEP (or similar if necessary) instead - `b[$3,$4]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***EDIT:*** Since OP has changed Input_file's sample data so adding this solution now.

```
awk '
FNR==NR{
  a[$3,$4,$5]=$3
  b[$3,$4,$5]=$4
  next
}
{
  val=$1 SUBSEP $2 SUBSEP $9
  val_last=$1 OFS $2
}
(val in a){
  $2=b[val]
  $1=a[val]
  print $0,"R",val_last
  next
}
{
  print $0,"O",val_last
}'  Input_file1  Input_file2  | column -t
```

---

---

Seems your shown expected output is not matching conditions which you have explained if that is the case could you please try following(tested with your shown samples only).

```
awk '
FNR==NR{
  a[$1,$2,$5]=$3
  b[$1,$2,$5]=$4
  next
}
{
  val=$1 SUBSEP $2 SUBSEP $9
}
(val in a){
  $2=b[val]
  $1=a[val]
  print $0,"R"
  next
}
{
  print $0,"O"
}'  Input_file1   Input_file2
```

***Why OP's code is not working:*** Because once `$1` i changed from Input_file1 then next element can't be set since $1 value of current line is changed to Input_file1's $1 now.

Comment: RavinderSingh13, the code works, but write in the end of column always R, ?. , Also please i have changed a little the output file adding columns columns 1 and 2 from file1 for matched records

Comment: @OXXO, I have added EDIT solution as per your new samples. NOTE that for printing `R` thing it is happening because in your shown samples all conditions are meeting(meaning all `$1,$2,$5` from Input_file1 looks to be same as `$1,$2,$9` from Input_file2), try to change samples bit and it will print `O` I had tested it previously too. Let me know then.

Comment: RavinderSingh13, it works perfectly now, only the issue of R in all records. I will like to have the R only for lines where the replacement was done to identify the lines changed..

Comment: @OXXO, As previously I mentioned it is because your condition is meeting for all samples shown, I did a small change of file2 last line and see it is printing output as `36835.00  3719121.00  8640   36840.00  37260.00  37146.00  37624.00  36  2606 O 36835.00 3719121.00` Let me know?

Comment: RavinderSingh13, Is there the possibility to compare $3,$4,$5 from Input_file1 with $1,$2,$9 from Input_file2 to get the lines where values of columns $1,$2 where modified in the output file?. Then perhaps the R and O option works.

Comment: RavinderSingh13, Is there the possibility to compare $3,$4,$5 from Input_file1 with $1,$2,$9 from Input_file2 to get the lines where values of columns $1,$2 where modified in the output file?. Then perhaps the R and O option works.

Comment: @OXXO,please check my EDIT now and let me know.

Answer (score 0):

tried on gnu awk

```
 awk 'NR==FNR{r[NR]=$0;next} {x=split(r[FNR],a);if(a[1]==$1&&a[2]==$2&&a[5]==$9){$1=a[3];$2=a[4];print $0,"R",a[1],a[2]} else {print $0,"O",a[1],a[2]}}' file1 file2
```